# npm install sqlite3 takes forever

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, installation

I am trying to install sqlite3 for use in node.js. However, the installation takes forever and is stuck at the bottom line below.

I have waited at least 15 minutes for anything to happen.

I have also tried installing with `--build-from-source` appended, with same same result.

The device I am installing on is a Raspberry Pi, and rebooting it does not solve the issue. Other packages such as `socket.io` has been installed successfully previously.

```
npm install sqlite3
npm WARN package.json ServerGPS@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json ServerGPS@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ServerGPS@1.0.0 No README data
/
> sqlite3@3.0.8 install /home/pi/ServerGPS/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
make: Entering directory '/home/pi/ServerGPS/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3080900/sqlite3.c
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3080900/sqlite3.o
```

Comment: exact the same issue here

Answer (score 7):

I originally thought that @travisWebb answer correct, but with time even that build failed with a `Unable to copy file...` error. Going back to try and find a solution I came across a post on [GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/933#issuecomment-389759765) looking for a way to make sure I had the build essentials. I came across this answer instead and it worked, relatively quickly at that.

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --sqlite=/usr
```

Comment: +1. Had this issue installing sqlite3 on Termux for Android. `apt-get libsqlite3-dev` doesn't find it. `apt-get libsqlite3` says it already has it. I just used the second line, `npm i sqlite3 --build-from-source --sqlite=/usr`. It built(?) sqlite3 right away. I then `npm i`''d the remaining modules normally, and got to use my app.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at [dblite](https://github.com/WebReflection/dblite). Is a wrapper for **sqlite**.

```
var dblite = require('dblite'),
    db = dblite('file.name');

// Asynchronous, fast, and ...
db.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, rows) {
  // ... that easy!
});
```

`npm install dblite`

Answer (score 2):

> The device I am installing on is a Raspberry Pi,

The sqlite3 driver is a native module, and needs to be compiled during installation. This compilation will take much longer on a slower processor.

Comment: I was waiting for the "build" to finish and fell asleep waiting, but decided to check SO before I killed the process. Right before I did the install progressed past the point shown by the OP. Expect, no joke, between an hour or two, on a PI Zero.

Comment: About 20 minutes later it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I used to install sqlite3 npm package on my rasperry pi 3 nodejs projects like this :

`npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --sqlite=/usr`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this on a Pi 2, and other packages worked fine. However, SQLITE3 would load almost all the way, filling the progress bar, and then stop (the place it stopped wasn't even consistent!)

I came here and tried

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --sqlite=/usr
```

and it looked like nothing was going to change, but a couple minutes later it finished installing! I don't know if this is what fixed it or that was just a lucky try, but for sure Pis are slow.